# Simplifying MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Is there a way to simplify the query below? I got what i wanted but i want to  learn how to achieve the result by using a shorter query. As for the result, can i replace the value NULL to 0?

```
SELECT ad.Staff, 
       ad.TYear, 
       ad.TWeek, 
       b.TMonth 
  FROM (SELECT a.Staff, 
               a.TYear, 
               d.TWeek
          FROM (SELECT t2.creatorfullname AS Staff, 
                      count(distinct(t1.ticketmaskid)) AS TYear 
                 FROM swtickets t1 
                      JOIN swticketauditlogs t2 
                           ON t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid 
                WHERE (YEAR(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                       AND FIND_IN_SET (t2.creatorfullname,'Andy Murray,Rafael Nadal,Maria Sharapova') > 0 
                       AND t2.actionmsg LIKE '%Ticket status changed from: % to: Closed%') 
                       AND totalreplies > 0 
              GROUP BY t2.creatorfullname) AS a 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t2.creatorfullname AS Staff, 
                                        count(distinct(t1.ticketmaskid)) AS TWeek 
                                   FROM swtickets t1 
                                        JOIN swticketauditlogs t2 
                                             ON t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid 
                                  WHERE (WEEK(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = WEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                                         AND FIND_IN_SET (t2.creatorfullname,'Andy Murray,Rafael Nadal,Maria Sharapova') > 0 
                                         AND t2.actionmsg LIKE '%Ticket status changed from: % to: Closed%') 
                                         AND totalreplies > 0  
                                GROUP BY t2.creatorfullname) AS d 
                                 ON (a.Staff = d.Staff)) AS ad 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT t2.creatorfullname AS Staff, 
                                        count(distinct(t1.ticketmaskid)) AS TMonth 
                                   FROM swtickets t1 
                                        JOIN swticketauditlogs t2 
                                             ON t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid 
                                  WHERE (MONTH(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                                         AND FIND_IN_SET (t2.creatorfullname,'Andy Murray,Rafael Nadal,Maria Sharapova') > 0 
                                         AND t2.actionmsg LIKE '%Ticket status changed from: % to: Closed%') 
                                         AND totalreplies > 0  
                                GROUP BY t2.creatorfullname) AS b 
                                 ON (ad.Staff = b.Staff);
```

```
+----------------+-------+-------+--------+
| Staff          | TYear | TWeek | TMonth |
+----------------+-------+-------+--------+
| Andy Murray    |   337 |    37 |    142 |
| Rafael Nadal   |    49 |  NULL |     13 |
| Maria Sharapova|    49 |     1 |      4 |
+----------------+-------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Removed sql-server tag because question is explicitly about MySQL.

Comment: please provide some sample data with expected output

Comment: Here we go again @Gordon

Comment: You could use coalesce  to show 0 instead of null, like coalesce(ad.TWeek,0)

Comment: coalesce works! Thank @RobertRozas . As for simplifying the query.. any suggestion?

Comment: your column of  "AND totalreplies > 0", there is no alias or table reference to confirm its origin... which table t1 or t2

Comment: Any idea how to integrate a sum value at the bottom of the row? I tried WITH ROLLUP but it doesnt output the correct sum value.

Comment: Anyone knows how to rollup the values?

Comment: i can use "with rollup" only if i requery it.

select Staff, Sum(TYear) as TYear, Sum(TWeek as TWeek, Sum(TMonth) as TMonth FROM (SELECT

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 SELECT t2.creatorfullname AS Staff, 
        count(distinct case when YEAR(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                       then t1.ticketmaskid end) AS TYear,
        count(distinct case when WEEK(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = WEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                       then t1.ticketmaskid end) AS TWeek,
        count(distinct case when MONTH(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                       then t1.ticketmaskid end) AS TMonth  
 FROM swtickets t1 
 JOIN swticketauditlogs t2 
      ON t1.ticketid = t2.ticketid 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET (t2.creatorfullname,'Andy Murray,Rafael Nadal,Maria Sharapova') > 0 
   AND t2.actionmsg LIKE '%Ticket status changed from: % to: Closed%' 
   AND totalreplies > 0 
 GROUP BY t2.creatorfullname
```

**-- edit --** 
This approach can be used when we need to count records that meet many conditions.
In this approach we use the simplest form of a **case expression**: 
`CASE WHEN condition THEN expression1 [ ELSE expression2 ] END`
The case expression works like `IF` statement - it evaluates a condition, and when the condition is true, then returns a result of first expression, otherwise a result of second expression, or - when the second expression is not given (`else` part is skipped) - it returns `NULL`.
MySql has an IF function: `IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)` that works in the same way as case expressions, however case expressions are part of ANSII SQL Standard and are implemented by most databases, while `IF` function is MySql's proprietary extension.
Please take a look at this link for details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html

The query to count records may look for example like:

```
SELECT count(*),
       count( some_column ),
       count( CASE WHEN condition1 THEN 1 END ),
       count( IF( condition2, 1, null ) ),
       sum( CASE WHEN condition3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ),
       count( DISTINCT CASE WHEN condition4 THEN some_column END ),
       count( DISTINCT IF( condition2, 1, some_column ) )
FROM sometable
```

`COUNT(*)` - counts a total number of rows
`COUNT( expression )` - counts a number of rows when `expression` is not null (it skips null values)
`COUNT( DISTINCT expression )` - same as above, but takes into account only distinct values

`count( DISTINCT CASE WHEN condition THEN some_column END )`
 -for each row it evaluates `condition` and returns a value of `some_column` when the condition is true, else returns null. Since nulls are skipped, it counts only distinct values for rows that meet the condition.

Comment: exactly where I was going, but pending on where "totalreplies" table basis was as it was not qualfied.

Comment: Its from the table t1.

Comment: It works. awesome!So i dont need to use LEFT OUTER JOIN as well as coalesce. Can you explain a bit

Comment: Also can u help me out with "last week", "last month" and "today"? Abit struggle playing with the dates

Comment: @user1204671 i've appended an explanation. If you want a previous year/month/week, just append `-1` to the condition, for example: `YEAR(from_unixtime(t2.dateline)) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1`

Comment: Nice one @kordirko what about just today and yesterday?

Comment: Any idea how to integrate a sum value at the bottom of the row? I tried WITH ROLLUP but it doesnt output the correct sum value.

Comment: i can use "with rollup" accurately only if i requery it.

select Staff, Sum(TYear) as TYear, Sum(TWeek as TWeek, Sum(TMonth) as TMonth FROM (SELECT